# AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'split' In Lxml Parsing

Tags: python

I have a code like this and it shows error like This:
Error:

```
{'chapter_id': '', 'posuk': '', 'text_heb': '', 'text_eng': '', 'text_both': ''}
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "parseheb.py", line 23, in <module>
    c_perek = raw_text.split(':')
AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'split'
```

Code:

```
for story in tree.xpath('//Story'):
    tmp = {'chapter_id':current_chapter_id, 'posuk':current_posuk, 'text_heb':'', 'text_eng':'', 'text_both':''}
    childs = story.getchildren()

    for child in childs:
        if child.tag == 'C_Perek':
            raw_text = child.text
            c_perek = raw_text.split(':')
            tmp['chapter_id'] = c_perek[0]
            tmp['posuk'] =c_perek[1]
            current_chapter_id = tmp['chapter_id']
            current_posuk = tmp['posuk']
    print(tmp)
```

Why Such Type of Error .. Sorry For My English Hope U will Understand My Error

Answer (score 0):

In this part of your code -

```
raw_text = child.text
c_perek = raw_text.split(':')
```

`child.text` returns you `None` and you can't perform split on `None`. You could wrap your code in an `if` before doing these operations -

```
raw_text = child.text
if raw_text:
    c_perek = raw_text.split(':')
    tmp['chapter_id'] = c_perek[0]
    tmp['posuk'] =c_perek[1]
    current_chapter_id = tmp['chapter_id']
    current_posuk = tmp['posuk']
```

Also, if there is no ":" colon in your text, `tmp['posuk'] =c_perek[1]` will also throw you `IndexError`

Answer (score 0):

First you need to specify more topic for the question like "lxml" "xml".
The problem is that the element *child* does not have text so the element returned is a None and so can't be splitted.

Can you past an example of the xml you're trying to parse?